# Animar script que troca o "src=" de uma imagem

Tags: javascript, css, animação

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto e não manjo muito de javascript. Consegui fazer esse código para trocar a imagem principal conforme é clicado na thumb. O único problema é que gostaria que tivesse alguma animação na hora que é trocado a imagem. Pode ser um fadeIn, somente para não ficar uma troca seca. É possível animar essa troca?

```js
function trocaFoto(e) {
  let foto = document.getElementById(e);
  let srcFoto = foto.src;
  let fotoPrincipal = document.querySelector('#fotoPrincipal');
  let containerImg = foto.parentNode;
  let containers = '.containerImg';
  containers = document.querySelectorAll(containers);
  containers.forEach((item)=> {
    if (item.classList.contains('--active')){
      item.classList.remove('--active');
    }
  });
  fotoPrincipal.src = srcFoto;      
  containerImg.classList.add('--active');
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins");

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #fff;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #171517;
}

#produtos {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#produtos .produto #produto-1 {
  top: 116px;
  right: 225px;
}
#produtos .produto #produto-2 {
  top: 376px;
  left: 200px;
}
#produtos .produto #produto-3 {
  top: 541px;
  right: 133px;
}
#produtos .produto #produto-4 {
  top: 525px;
  left: 229px;
}
#produtos .produtos__thumbs {
  margin-top: -60px;
  position: relative;
  left: -15px;
}
#produtos .produtos__thumbs .col.px-1 {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#produtos .produtos__thumbs .col.px-1 .--active {
  border-bottom: 6px solid #171517;
}
#produtos .produtos__thumbs .col.px-1 img {
  transition: 0.3s;
}
#produtos .produtos__thumbs .col.ml-1.p-0 {
  padding-bottom: 6px !important;
}
#produtos .produtos__thumbs .col.ml-1.p-0 .bg-dark {
  background-color: #171517 !important;
  width: calc(100% - .25rem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section id="produtos" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1000">
    <div class="container produto">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
       <div class="position-relative">
        <div id="container__produto">
         <div>
          <img src="//lucasgranvilla.com.br/produto1.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid" id="fotoPrincipal">
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid p-0 produtos__thumbs">
     <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-md-6"></div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col px-1">
         <div class="containerImg --active">
          <img src="//lucasgranvilla.com.br/produto1.jpg" alt="" id="thumb-1" class="img-fluid thumb--active" onClick="trocaFoto(this.id)">
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col px-1">
         <div class="containerImg">
          <img src="//lucasgranvilla.com.br/produto2.jpg" alt="" id="thumb-2" class="img-fluid" onClick="trocaFoto(this.id)">
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col px-1">
         <div class="containerImg">
          <img src="//lucasgranvilla.com.br/produto3.jpg" alt="" id="thumb-3" class="img-fluid" onClick="trocaFoto(this.id)">
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col ml-1 p-0">
         <div class="bg-dark w-100 h-100"></div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quero deixar aqui como referência uma forma de o fazer utilizando apenas javascript. Naturalmente não é tão simples como jQuery (como tem na resposta do [user140828](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/387452/82711)), mas também não é nada do outro mundo. Não modifiquei o html, para tornar a transição mais bonita e por isso ela é menos agradável aos olhos, ainda assim demonstra o *fadeIn* e *fadeOut* perfeitamente.

Nesta primeira solução, tentei ser o mais direto possível, e sem usar funções, por isso o código é mais curto mas mais confuso. Existem 2 `setInterval`, em que o primeiro se encarrega por reduzir a opacidade até 0, dando assim o efeito de *fadeOut*, e quando esse temporizador termina, passa a outro que volta a aumentar a opacidade até 100 já com o novo fundo. Os tempos (10 e 2) foram colocados manualmente e representam a velocidade da animação.

Exemplo:

```js
function trocaFoto(e) {
  let foto = document.getElementById(e);
  let srcFoto = foto.src;
  let fotoPrincipal = document.querySelector('#fotoPrincipal');
  let containerImg = foto.parentNode;
  let containers = '.containerImg';
  containers = document.querySelectorAll(containers);
  containers.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.classList.contains('--active')) {
      item.classList.remove('--active');
    }
  });

  //codigo novo começa aqui
  let opacidade = 100;
  let temporizador = setInterval(function(){
    if (opacidade > 0){
      opacidade -= 2;
      fotoPrincipal.style.opacity = opacidade / 100;
    }
    else { //quando termina o fadeOut
      clearInterval(temporizador);
      fotoPrincipal.src = srcFoto; //codigo já existente
      containerImg.classList.add('--active'); //codigo já existente
      
      temporizador = setInterval(function(){ //inicia o fadeIn
        if (opacidade < 100){
          opacidade += 2;
          fotoPrincipal.style.opacity = opacidade / 100;
        }
        else {
          clearInterval(temporizador);
        }
      }, 10);
    }
  }, 10);

}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins");
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #fff;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #171517;
}

#produtos {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#produtos .produto #produto-1 {
  top: 116px;
  right: 225px;
}

#produtos .produto #produto-2 {
  top: 376px;
  left: 200px;
}

#produtos .produto #produto-3 {
  top: 541px;
  right: 133px;
}

#produtos .produto #produto-4 {
  top: 525px;
  left: 229px;
}

#produtos .produtos__thumbs {
  margin-top: -60px;
  position: relative;
  left: -15px;
}

#produtos .produtos__thumbs .col.px-1 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#produtos .produtos__thumbs .col.px-1 .--active {
  border-bottom: 6px solid #171517;
}

#produtos .produtos__thumbs .col.px-1 img {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#produtos .produtos__thumbs .col.ml-1.p-0 {
  padding-bottom: 6px !important;
}

#produtos .produtos__thumbs .col.ml-1.p-0 .bg-dark {
  background-color: #171517 !important;
  width: calc(100% - .25rem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section id="produtos" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1000">
  <div class="container produto">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="position-relative">
          <div id="container__produto">
            <div>
              <img src="//lucasgranvilla.com.br/produto1.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid" id="fotoPrincipal">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid p-0 produtos__thumbs">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-md-6"></div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col px-1">
            <div class="containerImg --active">
              <img src="//lucasgranvilla.com.br/produto1.jpg" alt="" id="thumb-1" class="img-fluid thumb--active" onClick="trocaFoto(this.id)">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col px-1">
            <div class="containerImg">
              <img src="//lucasgranvilla.com.br/produto2.jpg" alt="" id="thumb-2" class="img-fluid" onClick="trocaFoto(this.id)">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col px-1">
            <div class="containerImg">
              <img src="//lucasgranvilla.com.br/produto3.jpg" alt="" id="thumb-3" class="img-fluid" onClick="trocaFoto(this.id)">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col ml-1 p-0">
            <div class="bg-dark w-100 h-100"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Pode sempre abstrair a lógica que está a ser feita em funções, no caso com uma função de *fadeIn* e *fadeOut* por exemplo, em que não só recebe o elemento a aplicar o fade como o tempo e código a executar quando termina. Desta forma o código fica bem mais organizado, legível e fácil de reutilizar para outros casos, embore fique mais extenso.

Exemplo:

```js
function fadeOut(elemento, tempo, callback){
  let opacidade = 100, tempoInterval = tempo / 50;
  let temporizador = setInterval(function(){
    if (opacidade > 0){
      opacidade -= 2;
      elemento.style.opacity = opacidade / 100;
    }
    else {
      clearInterval(temporizador);
      if (callback){
        callback();
      }
    }
  }, tempoInterval);
}

function fadeIn(elemento, tempo, callback){
  let opacidade = 0, tempoInterval = tempo / 50;
  let temporizador = setInterval(function(){
    if (opacidade < 100){
      opacidade += 2;
      elemento.style.opacity = opacidade / 100;
    }
    else {
      clearInterval(temporizador);
      if (callback){
        callback();
      }
    }
  }, tempoInterval);
}

function trocaFoto(e) {
  let foto = document.getElementById(e);
  let srcFoto = foto.src;
  let fotoPrincipal = document.querySelector('#fotoPrincipal');
  let containerImg = foto.parentNode;
  let containers = '.containerImg';
  containers = document.querySelectorAll(containers);
  containers.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.classList.contains('--active')) {
      item.classList.remove('--active');
    }
  });
  

  fadeOut(fotoPrincipal, 200, function(){
    fotoPrincipal.src = srcFoto;
    containerImg.classList.add('--active');
    
    fadeIn(fotoPrincipal, 200); 
  });
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins");
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #fff;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #171517;
}

#produtos {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#produtos .produto #produto-1 {
  top: 116px;
  right: 225px;
}

#produtos .produto #produto-2 {
  top: 376px;
  left: 200px;
}

#produtos .produto #produto-3 {
  top: 541px;
  right: 133px;
}

#produtos .produto #produto-4 {
  top: 525px;
  left: 229px;
}

#produtos .produtos__thumbs {
  margin-top: -60px;
  position: relative;
  left: -15px;
}

#produtos .produtos__thumbs .col.px-1 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#produtos .produtos__thumbs .col.px-1 .--active {
  border-bottom: 6px solid #171517;
}

#produtos .produtos__thumbs .col.px-1 img {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#produtos .produtos__thumbs .col.ml-1.p-0 {
  padding-bottom: 6px !important;
}

#produtos .produtos__thumbs .col.ml-1.p-0 .bg-dark {
  background-color: #171517 !important;
  width: calc(100% - .25rem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section id="produtos" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1000">
  <div class="container produto">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="position-relative">
          <div id="container__produto">
            <div>
              <img src="//lucasgranvilla.com.br/produto1.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid" id="fotoPrincipal">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid p-0 produtos__thumbs">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-md-6"></div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col px-1">
            <div class="containerImg --active">
              <img src="//lucasgranvilla.com.br/produto1.jpg" alt="" id="thumb-1" class="img-fluid thumb--active" onClick="trocaFoto(this.id)">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col px-1">
            <div class="containerImg">
              <img src="//lucasgranvilla.com.br/produto2.jpg" alt="" id="thumb-2" class="img-fluid" onClick="trocaFoto(this.id)">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col px-1">
            <div class="containerImg">
              <img src="//lucasgranvilla.com.br/produto3.jpg" alt="" id="thumb-3" class="img-fluid" onClick="trocaFoto(this.id)">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col ml-1 p-0">
            <div class="bg-dark w-100 h-100"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Neste ultimo exemplo forcei a animação a ter 50 passos, sendo que esta medida vai definir se a animação é muito brusca ou mais gradual, apesar do tempo ser o mesmo. Consegue perceber melhor esta medida comparando estes dois cenários:

- Aumentar 0.1 por segundo 10 vezes, que dá 10 segundos
- Aumentar 0.5 por cada 5 segundos 2 vezes, que dá 10 segundos

Em ambos os casos o tempo de animação é o mesmo, mas a primeira variante, que tem mais passos na animação, é mais suave.

Comment: Cara, para aprendizado isso me ajuda muito a entender o que está sendo feito! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!

Answer (score 3):

Bom, estou vendo que no seu código você está incluindo jQuery, apesar de não estar utilizando-o. Se a solução pode ser con jQuery, você pode usar os métodos `fadeOut` e `fadeIn` como no exemplo abaixo.

**Edit**

Também estou adicionando uma imagem ao fundo para a transição ficar mais suave, de uma foto para a outra, sem a tela em branco entre a transição de imagens.

```js
function trocaFoto(e) {
  let foto = document.getElementById(e);
  let srcFoto = foto.src;
  let fotoPrincipal = document.getElementById('fotoPrincipal');
  let fotoFundo = document.getElementById('fotoFundo');
  let containerImg = foto.parentNode;
  let containers = '.containerImg';
  containers = document.querySelectorAll(containers);
  containers.forEach((item)=> {
    if (item.classList.contains('--active')){
      item.classList.remove('--active');
    }
  });
  
  fotoFundo.src = srcFoto;
  $(fotoPrincipal).fadeOut(function() {
    fotoPrincipal.src = srcFoto;
    $(fotoPrincipal).show();
  })
       
  containerImg.classList.add('--active');
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins");

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #fff;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #171517;
}

#produtos {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#produtos .produto #produto-1 {
  top: 116px;
  right: 225px;
}
#produtos .produto #produto-2 {
  top: 376px;
  left: 200px;
}
#produtos .produto #produto-3 {
  top: 541px;
  right: 133px;
}
#produtos .produto #produto-4 {
  top: 525px;
  left: 229px;
}
#produtos .produtos__thumbs {
  margin-top: -60px;
  position: relative;
  left: -15px;
}
#produtos .produtos__thumbs .col.px-1 {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#produtos .produtos__thumbs .col.px-1 .--active {
  border-bottom: 6px solid #171517;
}
#produtos .produtos__thumbs .col.px-1 img {
  transition: 0.3s;
}
#produtos .produtos__thumbs .col.ml-1.p-0 {
  padding-bottom: 6px !important;
}
#produtos .produtos__thumbs .col.ml-1.p-0 .bg-dark {
  background-color: #171517 !important;
  width: calc(100% - .25rem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section id="produtos" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1000">
  <div class="container produto">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="position-relative">
          <div id="container__produto">
            <div>
              <img src="//lucasgranvilla.com.br/produto1.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid" id="fotoFundo"
                style="position:absolute; z-index: -1">
              <img src="//lucasgranvilla.com.br/produto1.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid" id="fotoPrincipal">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid p-0 produtos__thumbs">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-md-6"></div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col px-1">
            <div class="containerImg --active">
              <img src="//lucasgranvilla.com.br/produto1.jpg" alt="" id="thumb-1" class="img-fluid thumb--active"
                onClick="trocaFoto(this.id)">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col px-1">
            <div class="containerImg">
              <img src="//lucasgranvilla.com.br/produto2.jpg" alt="" id="thumb-2" class="img-fluid"
                onClick="trocaFoto(this.id)">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col px-1">
            <div class="containerImg">
              <img src="//lucasgranvilla.com.br/produto3.jpg" alt="" id="thumb-3" class="img-fluid"
                onClick="trocaFoto(this.id)">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col ml-1 p-0">
            <div class="bg-dark w-100 h-100"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Isto mesmo brother! Agradecido!